# Matlab genetic algorithm for instances selection problem with no convergence

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithms

This is my test using matlab ga function for instances selection or training set selection.
As you can see I used a simplified dataset to be sure of the performance.
You can see it in the first lines of the comment.
Separate training gives excellent results while aggregating the datasets the performance is bad.
I implemented ga thinking that the algorithm does not use a distance as a metric but
only the performances acquired. This way he doesn't have to know the values of
data underlying the selected indices. Despite everything ga can't find one
decent solution or, put another way, it doesn't work!
The solution in this case is sure so the problem is to be found in the algorithm
or in the way I use it.

If you find any errors or inaccuracies please let me know. I suppose there is a
logical architectural problem in the way the problem has been set.
Is there any way to use ga by choosing a subset from a fixed value dataset? Thanks !

```
%clear all;clearvars -global;

%[X1,t1] = simplefit_dataset;                              % 0.0076
%X2=X1.*2;t2=t1.*2;                                        % 0.0118
%X3=X1.*3;t3=t1.*3;                                        % 0.0076
%X4=X1.*4;t4=t1.*4;                                        % 0.0502

%perf=[];
%X=X4;t=t4;
%net = fitnet(10);  
%[net,tr] = train(net,X,t);
%Xval=X(tr.valInd);
%tval=t(tr.valInd); [mval,nval]=size(tval);
%outval=net(Xval);
%perf=mean(abs(tval-outval))

%XTOT= [X1,X2,X3,X4];                                       % 7.5016                   
%tTOT= [t1,t2,t3,t4];
%perm=randperm(376);
%XTOT=XTOT(perm);
%tTOT=tTOT(perm);

%X=XTOT;t=tTOT;
%net = fitnet(10);  
%[net,tr] = train(net,X,t);
%Xval=X(tr.valInd);
%tval=t(tr.valInd); [mval,nval]=size(tval);
%outval=net(Xval);
%perf=mean(abs(tval-outval))

% ------------

clear all;clearvars -global;
global singletrain;global min_instances;
cnt=0;
%q = gcp('nocreate');[par,pool]=size(q);
%if par==0
%   parpool(6)
%end
 
 [X1,t1] = simplefit_dataset;                              % 0.0076
 X2=X1.*2;t2=t1.*2;                                        % 0.0118
 X3=X1.*3;t3=t1.*3;                                        % 0.0076
 X4=X1.*4;t4=t1.*4;                                        % 0.0502
 XTOT= [X1,X2,X3,X4];                                      % 7.5016      
 tTOT= [t1,t2,t3,t4];
 perm=randperm(376);
 XTOT=XTOT(perm);
 tTOT=tTOT(perm);

 singletrain(1,:)=XTOT;singletrain(2,:)=tTOT;
 [m,n]=size(singletrain);

selectmode = 'multimodal';   %'multimodal' or 'denoise'
selecttype = 'class';        %'class' or 'regre'
min_instances = 94;

nvar = {min(max(10*n,40),100)}; nvar =nvar{1,1};  


    initpop(1:n,1)=randperm(n);
    a = min_instances+1; b = n+1; r = floor((b-a).*rand(1,1) + a); r = n-r; 
    initzero(1:n,1)=randperm(n);initzero=initzero(1:r,1);
    initpop(initzero,1)=0; 


initpop=initpop';
IntCon = (1:n);
lb(1:n)=0;ub(1:n)=n;
options = optimoptions('ga','MaxTime',1800,'PlotFcn',@gaplotbestf,'UseVectorized',false,'InitialPopulation',initpop,'UseParallel',false,'MaxGeneration',1000); 
[perf,fval,ext,output] = ga(@GAfunc,n,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,@condition,IntCon,options);

function [perf] =  GAfunc (indices)  % selectmode = 'multimodal' & selecttype = 'class'

global singletrain;
    
[m,n]=size(indices);
   
perf=[];

indclean=indices(1,:); indclean = nonzeros(indclean); indclean = indclean';
X=singletrain(1,indclean(1,:));
t=singletrain(2,indclean(1,:));

net = fitnet(10);
net.trainParam.showWindow = false;
[net,tr] = train(net,X,t);
Xval=X(tr.valInd);
tval=t(tr.valInd); [mval,nval]=size(tval);
outval=net(Xval);
perf=mean(abs(tval-outval));

end



function [c,ceq] = condition(indices)

global min_instances;

ceq = [];go2local=[];

[m,n] = size(indices);
% condizioni globali 

if  sum(double(not(indices(1,1:n)==0))) >= min_instances 
    go2local=1;
    c(1,1:n)=0;
else
    go2local=0;
    c(1,1:n)=1;
end
    
%condizioni locali
 
 if go2local==1     

       indclean=indices(1,:); indclean = nonzeros(indclean); indclean = indclean';
       k = find(indices(1,:));
       
       if length(unique(indclean))==size(indclean(2))
           c(1,1:n)=0;
       else
           c(1,1:n)=0;
           f=double(isMultiple(indclean)); f=f';
           c(k)=f;
       end
   
 end


end

function T = isMultiple(A)
% T = isMultiple(A)
% INPUT:  A: Numerical or CHAR array of any dimensions.
% OUTPUT: T: TRUE if element occurs multiple times anywhere in the array.
%
% Tested: Matlab 2009a, 2015b(32/64), 2016b, 2018b, Win7/10
% Author: Jan, Heidelberg, (C) 2021
% License: CC BY-SA 3.0, see: creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
T        = false(size(A));
[S, idx] = sort(A(:).');
m        = [false, diff(S) == 0];
if any(m)        % Any equal elements found:
   m(strfind(m, [false, true])) = true;
   T(idx) = m;   % Resort to original order
end
end
```